# Understanding Interfaces and Abstract Classes

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract-class, phpseclib

I have never used Interfaces or Abstract Classes in PHP, but have come to a point where I want to support similar but different types of the same object (in this case Network Switches) and possibly add more in the future. I communicate with them via SSH (PHPSecLib) and which the interactions are different, the actual methods would be the same.

In my particular case I believe an Abstract Class, implementing the constants, private variables, connect functions and constructor/destructors would be appropriate, leaving the extended classes ONLY to implement the functionality, where an Interface would just be a template but each extended class would still re-implement methods that are the same between them.

Am I correct in thinking that Abstract Classes are the way to go in this scenario? Do you need to place empty methods in Abstract Classes which are overridden by extended classes or can the extended class have methods that don't exist in the Abstract class?

Example:

```
<?php

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/devicepo/public_html/include/PHPSecLib');

    include('Net/SSH2.php');
    include('File/ANSI.php');

    abstract class Switch
    {
        const STATUS_UNKNOWN = "-1";
        const STATUS_OFFLINE = "0";
        const STATUS_ONLINE = "1";

        public $conn;

        private $_server;
        private $_username;
        private $_password;

        private $_bashshell;

        public function __construct($server, $username, $password)
        {
            if (!$server)
                die("Switch configuration not Defined");

            $this->_server = $server;
            $this->_username = $username;
            $this->_password = $password;
        }

        public function connect()
        {
            // Establish new SSH2 Connection
            $this->conn = new Net_SSH2($this->_server, 22);

            if(!$this->conn->login($this->_username, $this->_password))
            {
                die("Failed to connect to Switch: " . $this->_server);
            }
        }

        public function enable_port($port)
        {
            // Define in extended classes
        }

        public function disable_port($port)
        {
            // Define in extended classes
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in your case the Abstract class is the way to go. The reasons are that:

1. Your child classes share a big part of code with the parent class
2. Your child classes have a notion of similarity.

To be more specific regarding point 2, keep in mind that two classes implementing the same interface are not necessarily related. The interface represents an ability. Consider for example an airplane and a bird. Both can implement a flyable interface, but except from that they are not related in any other way. On the other hand, your child classes have a similar type. They are all switches. So your abstract class could be

```
abstract class BasicSwitch { // You cannot use the name switch

    const STATUS_UNKNOWN = "-1";

    const STATUS_OFFLINE = "0";

    const STATUS_ONLINE = "1";

    public $conn;

    private $_server;

    private $_username;

    private $_password;

    private $_bashshell;

    public function __construct($server, $username, $password) {

        if (!$server) die("Switch configuration not Defined");

        $this->_server = $server;

        $this->_username = $username;

        $this->_password = $password;
    }

    public function connect() {

        // Establish new SSH2 Connection

        $this->conn = new Net_SSH2($this->_server, 22);

        if(!$this->conn->login($this->_username, $this->_password)) {

            die("Failed to connect to Switch: " . $this->_server);
        }
    }

    abstract public function enable_port($port);

    abstract public function disable_port($port);
}
```

and a concrete implementation could be

```
class CiscoSwitch extends BasicSwitch {

    public function __construct($server, $username, $password) {

        parent::__construct($server, $username, $password);
    }

    public function enable_port($port) {

        echo 'Port is enabled';
    }

    public function disable_port($port) {

        echo 'Port is disabled';
    }               
}
```

The most important think to keep in mind here is that CiscoSwitch is also a type of BasicSwitch. This means that a CiscoSwitch can be used anywhere a BasicSwitch is expected. So consider that you have a Rack with many switches and you want to enable the same port an all switches in the rack. Here is your Rack class:

```
class Rack {

    protected $switches;

    public function addSwitch(BasicSwitch $switch) {

        $this->switches[] = $switch;
    }

    public function enable_ports($port) {

        foreach($this->switches as $switch) {

            $switch->enable_port($port);
        }
    }
}
```

If you type hint on the Abstract class (BasicSwitch) and not on the implementation you can be sure that any switch inside the rack can enable and disable its ports. You really don't care which switch it is. You just know that it can do the job.
This is what code on an interface and not on implementation is all about. This way your code is open for extension but closed for modification. You can create as many switch types as you want but you will be sure that the Rack class will continue to work.